# Reuse Variables in Loop C#

Tags: c#, loops

I've got an app that takes values from a SQL compact database, assigns them to a variable and then calls a class for sending of files via FTP. The values in the database are related to up to 4 servers. Right now I'm taking each of these values, assigning to a variable then calling each of them but there has to be a better way of doing this such as reusing the variables and somehow using a loop instead. I just can't figure out how to do that. Any suggestions are much appreciated. To make my code shorter I'm just showing static values assigned instead of the query to give you an idea.

```
    private string ftpServer1 = @"ftp://10.0.0.0";
    private string ftpServer2 = @"ftp://10.0.0.1";
    private string ftpServer3 = @"ftp://10.0.0.2";
    private string ftpServer4 = @"ftp://10.0.0.3";
    private string ftpUser1 = @"user1";
    private string ftpPass1 = @"pass1";
    private string ftpUser2 = @"user2";
    private string ftpPass2 = @"pass2";
    private string ftpUser3 = @"user3";
    private string ftpPass3 = @"pass3";
    private string ftpUser4 = @"user4";
    private string ftpPass4 = @"pass4";
    private string ftpRemoteFile = @"myfile.exe";
    private string ftpLocalFile = @"C:\Files\myfile.exe";


    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        progressRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending to: " + ftpServer1;  }));
        ftp ftpClient1 = new ftp(ftpServer1, ftpUser1, ftpPass1);
        ftpClient.upload(worker, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);

        progressRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending to: " + ftpServer2;  }));
        ftp ftpClient2 = new ftp(ftpServer2, ftpUser2, ftpPass2);
        ftpClient2.upload(worker, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);

        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        progressRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending to: " + ftpServer3;  }));
        ftp ftpClient3 = new ftp(ftpServer3, ftpUser3, ftpPass3);
        ftpClient.upload(worker, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);

        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        progressRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending to: " + ftpServer4;  }));
        ftp ftpClient4 = new ftp(ftpServer4, ftpUser4, ftpPass4);
        ftpClient.upload(worker, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);

    }
```

Comment: You need to use arrays (or `List<T>`) and `foreach`.

Comment: Do they have to be variables? Seems like a class that has a property for server, user, password would be better. then have an array or collection of that class.

Comment: My ftp class already has a property for a server, user and password. But I have an app that the user will select a company from a list then based on what company is selected a list of available files displays and they click Send. When they send I'll be using a loop that runs while ftpserver != null else loop through 4x to send to all servers in the database. I need to get the server, user and pass assigned to a variable though so I can use them in the mainform.cs, and pass to my ftp.cs. I also reference the server variable in another method of my form as well for status messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would create a structure to hold server params:

```
struct FTPServerParams // needs better name
{
    public readonly string Address;
    public readonly string UserName;
    public readonly string Password;

    public FTPServerParams(string address, string userName, string password)
    {
        Address = address;
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

And then I would put params for all the servers in a list:

```
class YourClass
{
    private readonly List<FTPServerParams> ftpServersParams = new List<FTPServerParams>();

    public YourClass()
    {
        ftpServersParams.Add(new FTPServerParams(@"ftp://10.0.0.0", @"user1", @"pass1"));
        ftpServersParams.Add(new FTPServerParams(@"ftp://10.0.0.1", @"user2", @"pass2"));
        ftpServersParams.Add(new FTPServerParams(@"ftp://10.0.0.2", @"user3", @"pass3"));
    }

    ...
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    foreach (var serverParams in ftpServersParams)
    {
        progressRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressRichTextBox.Text = "Sending to: " + serverParams.Address; }));
        ftp ftpClient1 = new ftp(serverParams.Address, serverParams.UserName, serverParams.Password);
        ftpClient.upload(worker, ftpRemoteFile, ftpLocalFile);
    }
}
```